# Design File Problems

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I think I am onto some esoteric problem with the design file, but I am not sure.

I have a form with a tab control.  On Tab A there is a datagridview and a combo box.  The list source for the combo box is a datatableadapter.  The selectevalue is connected to a column in the datagridview.

This has been working great for a year.  Recently, the combo has lost its connection to the datagridview.  That is, clicking a row in the DGV doesn't make the combo update, and changing the selection in the combo doesn't make the DGV update.

Here is where it gets strange.  After a day and a half, I have found this much:

If I move the combo off of the tab, it works perfectly.  No code changes, nothing, just drag the combo and hit run.  If I drag it back on the tab, the problem comes back.

I rolled back to a working version and did a diff.  I started making code changes to the working version one line at a time.  In the end, all changes were made and the problem did not happen.

So, I moved to the design file and did the same thing.  After lots of process, I found that there is one particular text box on the form (outside the tab control).  If in the designer I have the line to set the text box visible property to false, the problem with the text box comes back.  If I remove that line from the designer, the problem goes away.

I am at a loss.  What have I stumbled onto and is there a way to fix it?  I have no problem if you tell me I have missed something.  Please, any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Design file is same code file as others. Only difference that content of this file is generated by Visual Studio when you make some changes through designer. I doubt that changing `TextBox.Visible` will break some data binding of `DataGridView` and `ComboBox`. Obviously some changes have "disabled" `DataSource - Detail` relationship between `DataGridView` and `ComboBox`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write Fabio.  I am with you that there is probably something I am missing here.  What I see is crazy so there must be something.  Don't miss the part that if I drag the combo off the tab it works as expected - more weirdness, right?